# Why .XValues don't accept that array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, charts, axis

i got some problems on understand why the array "ordem" not work and array "quant" does when i put them on ".XValues" and ".Values" on my series s.

Here are the function what i create to get this array "ordem"

```
'Função que cria o vetor ordenado com as idades contidas em outro, eixo x
Function OrdemIdade(dados)
    Dim Max, Min As Integer
    ReDim ordem(1 To 10000) As Integer
    k = 0
    n = UBound(dados)
    Max = 0
    Min = 150
    For i = 1 To n
        If (dados(i) < Min) Then
            Min = dados(i)
        End If
        If (dados(i) > Max) Then
            Max = dados(i)
        End If
    Next i
    For j = Min To Max
        k = k + 1
        ordem(k) = j
    Next j
    ReDim Preserve ordem(1 To k) As Integer
    OrdemIdade = ordem
End Function
```

And here is the subroutine that doesnt work because "ordem" array

```
Sub GerarGraficosBD()
    'Premissas
    plano = "BD"
    AnoAtual = 2012
    'Tentativa de gerar grafico de colunas das idades
    dados = DadosIdades(plano, AnoAtual)
    ordem = OrdemIdade(dados)
    quant = QuantidadeIdade(dados, ordem)
    xaxis = ordem
    yaxis = quant
    Dim c As Chart
    Set c = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
    Set c = c.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="PlanoBD")
    With c
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked 'A column plot!
         'set other chart properties
    End With
    Dim s As Series
    Set s = c.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With s
        .Values = yaxis
        .XValues = xaxis 'PROBLEM HERE, ON THAT LINE/ PROBLEMA NESTA LINHA! PORQUE!?!?
        ' set other series properties
    End With
    With c
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Idade"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Quantidade"
        .HasLegend = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Sorry about fomatted code, my machine is an outdated one

Comment: "doesn't work" is a bit unprecise. What does not work? what do you expect and what does happen instead?

Comment: I'm not smart enough to figure out from your code what the arrays look like. If you dump them into the worksheet for inspection, do they look okay? Can you used these ranges in a chart?

Comment: Yes @JonPeltier, i put all values on cells and they are okay and with theses ranges my series work on a plot.
Im starting to think the problem is about a limitation of characteres on series plot, because "=MySheet!$A$1:$Z$99" is short than write "={1.2.3.4. (...) 7998.7999.8000}"

Comment: You should recognize that Excel charts were designed to plot Excel worksheet ranges; this means it will be better to dump arrays into a worksheet and plot the cell ranges. I have found this to be rather reliable, and easy to debug when it fails.

Comment: Your array "={1.2.3.4. (...) 7998.7999.8000}" uses periods as element separators? Not commas or semicolons?

Comment: Yeah, again. @JonPeltier
Its because language, pt-br excel accept "." as separators.
But writing a VBA code i should write normal, with "," as separators.